# Do we continue to draw additional tiles after the initial meld?

Tags: rummikub

The rules in my Rummikub set state that if you cannot play the initial 'meld' of 30 points then you take an extra tile on your turn.

Once the initial meld is over, do you still draw an extra tile if it is your turn and you cannot play any tiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes.  this is very clear stated in the [rules](https://tesera.ru/images/items/784463/Rummikub_Rules.pdf)

> After players have made their initial plays, they can also build on
>   other sets on the table with tiles from their racks. If a player
>   cannot add onto the other sets, the player picks a tile from the pouch
>   and the turn ends.